# marshmallow nested change schema behavior

Tags: python

I would like to know how to pass context to a nested Schema field so that
it serializes differently than if it was not nested.

I have a Schema subclass that adds some things in a `@post_dump` depending on some `flag` arg:

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    def __init__(self, flag=False, *args, **kwargs):
        self.flag = flag
        super(MySchema, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

     @post_dump
     def add_thing(self, data):
         if self.flag:
              #add {'NESTED' : 'some_value'} to data
         else:
              #add {'NOT_NESTED' : 'some_value'} to data
         return data
```

I have a standard nested schema that roughly looks like :

```
class ASchema(MySchema):
  id = fields.Integer()
  b  = fields.Nested(BSchema, flag=True)

class BSchema(MySchema):
  x = fields.Integer()
  y = fields.Integer()
```

where I end up with a serialization of ASchema that looks like :

```
{ 'id' : 5,
  'NOT_NESTED' : 'some_value',
  'b'  : { 'x' : 10,
           'y' : 15,
           'NOT_NESTED' : 'some_value',
         }
}
```

If my BSchema is Nested, I would like for the post_dump in MySchema to be able to tell via flag.

Looking at the source for `fields.Nested()`, it passes some `**kwargs` up to `Field.__init__()`, but in the `_serialize()` method, it just returns `Bschema.dump()`.

Do I have any options for changing the serialization of a field depending on whether it is nested?

Comment: Maybe subclass Nested field to add your functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure `Nested` with a schema instance, not just schema class. That way you can configure it the way you like:

```
class ASchema(MySchema):
  id = fields.Integer()
  b  = fields.Nested(BSchema(flag=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating a `field.Nested` subclass that would mark the Schema as nested:

```
class FlaggedNestedField(fields.Nested):

    @property
    def schema(self):
        schema = super(FlaggedNestedField, self).schema
        setattr(schema, "nested", True)
        return schema
```

Then I created a Schema subclass that my other schema extend, that uses the flag to decide what to do in `@post_dump`:

```
class MySchema(Schema):

    @post_dump(pass_many=True)
    def wrap_with_envelope(self, data, many):
        if getattr(self, "nested", False):
            return data

        return {"data": data}
```

This was necessary because dependencies between schema prevented me from using a Schema instance.